# TabLayout not aligning to top of ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-tablayout

I'm trying to get a TabLayout aligned to the top of a ConstraintLayout but somehow there is a gap between them.

This is the fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.equipment.EquipmentFragment"
>
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Monday"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tuesday"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wednesday"/>
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is how it looks like on the emulator:

[image]

I'm unsure what the issue is. The fragment was just created, TabLayout added and I added some constrains to it with what I thought would make it properly aligned but no.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: This could be from the activity; try to add a background color to the ConstraintLayout and check if you see it on the launch

Comment: @Zain I changed the color of the activity and the ConstraintLayout to different colors and it's definitely due to the activity.
Thanks for the tip. It was actually a padding in the activity that came with the new project.

Comment: If you run into stuff like this, open the Layout Inspector in Android Studio while the app's running in an emulator, and you can poke around at the layout and see what's going on - it can be quicker than trying changes when you're not really sure where the problem lies!